# Find size of file in unix using for loop

Tags: bash

I am trying to get the size of each file in a directory using a for loop, running the below script

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE=/home/cloudera/Desktop/new
for    file in $FILE
do
       size=`du -b ${file} | cut -f1`
       echo $size
done
```

I am getting following error:

```
du cannot access /home/cloudera/Desktop/new/a.txt 
du cannot access /home/cloudera/Desktop/new/b.txt 
du cannot access /home/cloudera/Desktop/new/c.txt
```

where a.txt,b.txt.c.txt are files inside new directory.

Comment: Where do you define or assign a value to `$i`? Where do you use `$file`?

Comment: please replace i with file

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `du -b`, may I suggest you use find with printf. The main problem here is that du will recurse into any directories it finds. Your `for` loop is unable to see the individual files.

```
find /home/cloudera/Desktop/new -type f -printf "%s %p\n"
```

If your find doesn't have printf, then use

```
-exec stat -c "%s %n" {} \;
```

Then pipe the output to a while script:

```
find <what you do above> | 
while read size ; do 
   # whatever
done
```

EDIT: You seem to want to find each file in SOURCEDIR and if the file does not exist in DESTDIR or if the file does exist but has a different file size, copy that file.

```
CP="echo /bin/cp -f"
sizeof() { stat -c %s "%1" ; }
cd $SOURCEDIR
find . -type f -print |
  while read name; do
    source_size=$(sizeof $SOURCEDIR/$name)
    if [[ -f $DESTDIR/$name ]]; then
      dest_size=$(sizeof $DESTDIR/$name)
      if [[ $source_size == $dest_size ]]; then
        next # do not copy
      fi
    fi
    $CP $SOURCEDIR/$name $DESTDIR/$name
  done
```

But that's ugly and slow. The `cd` is necessary to make sure find's output are all relative paths. The subsequent use of `$SOURCEDIR` is redundant and for clarity. I alias the `sizeof` so that you can change it to `du -b` or whatever. 
When the output looks right to you, change `$CP` to the real command (remove `echo`).

Here's another way to do this. If you learn it well, you will master many things about unix:

```
CP="echo cp"
{ cd $SOURCEDIR ; find . -type f -printf "%s %p\n" |sort -k 2 ; } >/tmp/source.lst
{ cd $DESTDIR   ; find . -type f -printf "%s %p\n" |sort -k 2 ; } >/tmp/dest.lst
awk 'FNR==NR { f[$2]=$1 } !length(f[$2]) || f[$2]!=$1 { print $2 }' /tmp/dest.lst /tmp/source.lst >/tmp/copythese.lst
cat /tmp/copythese.lst | xargs -n 1 -I ^ $CP $SOURCEDIR/^ $DESTDIR/^
```

Test it. Then when the list looks right, change `CP` to `/bin/cp -f` and repeat last command. You're doing the above steps but using lists. The awk command finds files in source that are either not in dest or have a different size. ($1 is size, $2 is filename, $f[$2] is the size of the file in *dest*). Then the `xargs` runs an instance of `$CP` for each line in `copythese.lst`.

Comment: how can it be done using for loop.what i want is for file in directory get the fike size of each file.

Comment: Otheus: Given that @RajAbhishek does NOT want to recurse into any subdirectories, I believe that you're missing "-maxdepth 1" in your "find" command :-)

Comment: @Raj, just use the stat command `stat -c %s <filename>`

Comment: i wan to recurse into a directory ].i am a new bee in unix .my requirement to go through each file in a directory and then  finding its size.i was taking belo approach var=`ls $directory` ; for file in $var do get the size of 1st file in 1st run done.foe loop continues till all the files are accessed.

Comment: 1s i get the size of a.txt i have to compare its size with the destination file size.that is the reason i am taking foor loop approach that is why i want to get the size of each file one by one so the for loop rund till all the files are accessed.

Comment: @RajAbhishek  The `while-read` loop does what you want.  It's just an ordinary while loop but in each iteration, it reads one line of input from `find`. Do you need the filename? If so, let me know and I'll modify answer so you see how that's done. 

What do you then do with the file size? Compare it to another?

Comment: @Otheus i will take the source file $sourcepath/$i file size and will compare  it with $destinationpath/$i size.that is y a am trying to put thr content of source and desti nation path in a variable ie sourcefiles=`ls $sourcepath` and then for i in $sourcefiles do ge file size compare with destination done.you can go ahead with your logic.awaiting

Comment: i will tell you in detail.....i have a config file which contains data in pattern sourcepath|destinationpath|noofdays.........i am reading it line by line using while IFS='|' read -r sourcepath destinationpath noofdays do pathcontent=`ls $sourcepath`; for i in $pathcontent i am checking if the contet of sourcepath is not in the destination i am copying it to destination if it is thre i am checking if the size of the file in two location is same or not if not i am copying .

Comment: Do you want to copy ALL files from SOURCE-PATH to DESTINATION-PATH? What does "noofdays" have to do with anything?

Comment: yes all the source file to destinatination if it doesnot exist thre if it exist i will check the size if size mismacth the i will copy again else  do nuthing.no of days is not a mattter of concern

Comment: Well, you really should be using `rsync` which will do all the above and more. You probably want `rsync -vr $SOURCEDIR/. $DESTRDIR/.` Rsync will copy files only if needed (the source and destination files differ or don't exist on destination). If I misunderstood you and you want to copy files ONLY if they exist already in dest, then you need `--existing` in rsync. If you want to copy only files that are _newer_ in source, use `-u`.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
DIR=/home/cloudera/Desktop/new
for    file in $DIR/*
do
       wc -c "$file"
done
```

Comment: The answer is perfectly fine for size in bytes. Just to clarify: Note that `wc -c` will count bytes (not characters). Both happen to be equal for ASCII, but that's not true in general (UNICODE).

Comment: Wc - c sounds good but what if my file size is very big may terabytes or zetabytes...that won't be good to present..any other way can I get the human readable format using wc command in for loop

Comment: @RajAbhishek good point: echo `$((\`wc -c "$file" | cut -f 1 -d \ \` / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 ))` = terabytes :D

Answer (score 0):

This script shows a pair `<SIZE> <FILE>`, where `<SIZE>` is its own size in bytes and `<FILE>` can be a file or a directory. If you want to show only files you have to remove the first condition and use the second one.

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE=/home/cloudera/Desktop/new

for i in `ls $FILE`
do
    if [ -d "$FILE/$i" ]
    then
        msg=`ls -ld $FILE/$i`
        size=$(echo $msg | awk -F [\ ] '{print $5}')
        file=$(echo $msg | awk -F [\ ] '{print $9}')
        echo -e "$size \t  $file"

    elif [ -f "$FILE/$i" ]
    then
        msg=`ls -l $FILE/$i`
        size=$(echo $msg | awk -F [\ ] '{print $5}')
        file=$(echo $msg | awk -F [\ ] '{print $9}')
        echo -e "$size \t  $file"
    fi
done
```